# Use Times New Roman 12 pt in r markdown docx

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to use Times New Roman font in a .docx file using R markdown. I have tried adding the following in the YAML section:

`mainfont: "Times New Roman"`, `sansfont: Calibri Light` - both with and without quotes. I also specified a template:

```
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template1.docx
```

I had generated template1.docx using R markdown and changed some of the formattings like margin, line number, font size, font face, etc. and everything, but the font face gets copied to the main .docx file. Please help.

Comment: You need to show us a complete document.  It doesn't need to be your real one, but it needs to be something we could run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mainfont` argument only works for pdf output.

To make your Word document have a specific font, open your template document in Word. Go to the "Design" tab. The Fonts button allows you to select the default fonts for your headings and body text.

You can create your own font pairings if one of the available options is not to your liking. For example, you can create an option with Times New Roman for both headings and body text

Comment: Thank you. I was changing the font directly from the "Home" tab, and it wasn't working. Changing the font from the "Design" tab worked.